# Room : making an "one to one to many" relation

Tags: android, android-room

I am working with room persistence library in android.
I know to make an "one to many" relations, but I would like to know if it's possible to make an "one to one to many" relation.
Here is a simplified schema of my database (there is more columns in each table) : [image: db schema]

Here is the data class that links "Appointment" and "Diagnostic" :

```
data class AppointmentWithDiagnostic(
    @Embedded
    val appointment: Appointment,

    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "idDossier",
        entityColumn = "appointmentId"
    )
    val diagnostic: Diagnostic,
)
```

And the data class that links Diagnostic with description and survey :

```
data class DiagnosticWithDescriptionAndSurvey(
    @Embedded
    val diagnostic: Diagnostic,

    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "diagnosticId"
    )
    val description: Description,

    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "diagnosticId"
    )
    val survey: Survey,
)
```

I thought about making a request that links directly all the tables or linking directly Survey and Description directly to Appointment.
If it's not possible to make an "one to one to many" relation, I guess I would go with one of those solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could have:-

```
data class AppointmentWithDiagnostic(
    @Embedded
    val appointment: Appointment,

    @Relation(
        entity = Diagnostic::class, //<<<<<<<<< IMPORTANT 
        parentColumn = "idDossier",
        entityColumn = "appointmentId"
    )
    val diagnosticWithDescriptionAndSurvey: DiagnosticWithDescriptionAndSurvey,
)
```

- Note in-principle code not compiled or run (now compiled)
- if you don't specify the entity (IMPORTANT) then the compile will fail as the class defaults to the class of the field and that is not a table (`@Entity`).

  - e.g. `error: The class must be either @Entity or @DatabaseView. public final class DiagnosticWithDescriptionAndSurvey {`

Comment: It works but I had to make a little modification in code :
`val diagnosticWithDescriptionAndSurvey: DiagnosticWithDescriptionAndSurvey` instead of `val diagnosticWithDescriptionAndSurvey: Diagnostic`

Comment: @YohDono Oops sorry. Corrected now (normally I fully test before posting but feeling a little lazy)